# Android: Textviews in widget overlap as the widget does not take up full screen width on certain devices

Tags: java, android, android-widget

I have an Android app with target version as Android 2.2. The widget of my app was designed to take up the full width of the screen. The widget has two columns, each column has two textviews horizontally with 15sp font size. On most devices, the widget takes up the full width of the screen and it looks fine. But, on certain devices like Nexus 5, Xperia Z3, the widget does not take up the full screen and the textviews overlaps.

The layout_width of my widget is match_parent. Is there a way to force the widget to occupy the full screen or any other way to ensure that the textviews do not overlap?

[image]

Widget Provider

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <appwidget-provider  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:minWidth="250dp"
    android:minHeight="110dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="0"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/xyz"
    >
</appwidget-provider>
```

Below is my layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"                 android:layout_height="match_parent"             
android:padding="7dp"             
android:orientation="vertical" >                      

<LinearLayout                 
android:layout_width=“match_parent"                 android:layout_height=“match_parent"                 
android:orientation="vertical" >                                           

<RelativeLayout                     
android:layout_width="fill_parent"                     
android:layout_height="0dp"                     
android:layout_weight="100" >                              

<LinearLayout                   
android:layout_width="fill_parent"                         android:layout_height="fill_parent"                         
android:paddingTop="0dp"                         
android:paddingBottom="0dp"                         
android:paddingLeft="0dp"                         
android:paddingRight="0dp"                         
android:orientation="vertical" >                                  

<GridView                           
android:layout_width="fill_parent"                          android:layout_height="fill_parent"                              
android:numColumns="2"
android:padding="0dp"                             
android:layout_margin="0dp"                             
android:listSelector="@null">                           
</GridView>                                              
</LinearLayout>                             
</RelativeLayout>                      
</LinearLayout>                  
</RelativeLayout>
```

The GridView in above layout has the following child:

```
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"       android:layout_width="fill_parent"         
android:layout_height="fill_parent"         
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="horizontal"> 

     <LinearLayout            
android:layout_width="0dp"          
android:layout_height="fill_parent"             
android:paddingTop="3dp" 
android:paddingBottom="3dp"             
android:paddingLeft="7dp" 
android:paddingRight="7dp"      
android:layout_weight="1"           
android:clickable="true"            
android:focusable="true"            
android:orientation="vertical">                 
<RelativeLayout                 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"              
android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
android:orientation="horizontal" >                      

<TextView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"                    
android:text=“Text11111”
android:textSize="15sp"                     
android:layout_weight="1"                   
android:textColor="@color/black" />                     

<TextView                   
android:layout_width="wrap_content"                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"                  
android:text=“Text22222”
android:textSize="15sp"                         
android:layout_weight="1"                   
android:textColor="@color/black" />             

</RelativeLayout>               

<RelativeLayout                 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"              
android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
android:orientation="horizontal"                
android:paddingTop="-2dp">                      

<TextView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"                    
android:text=“Text33333”
android:textSize="15sp"
android:textColor="@color/black" />                     
<TextView                   
android:layout_width="wrap_content"                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"                  
android:text=“Text44444”
android:textSize="15sp"
android:textColor="@color/black" />            

</RelativeLayout>        
</LinearLayout>         
     </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your layout XML or code to show what you're doing already to setup the layout.

Comment: @HexAndBugs: Added my layout files